# Why was my answer deleted - is this arrogance from moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

When the first gamer comes to the pile for the last time there must be between 1 and 9 Euro in the pile. So the controller is worth between 1 and 9 Euro.

deleted by Rand al'Thor, Beastly Gerbil, Rubio

The above post was deleted by  saying "this does not provide and answer to the question". What do you think the first line of this post is?

Is this yet more arrogance from a moderator on a site that is supposed to be fun?

Comment: forgive me, but how is that arrogant?

Comment: (this is apparently re https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/29943)

Comment: I'm a Puzzling moderator who wasn't involved in the deletion of your answer. I think deleting it was entirely reasonable, for the reasons given in the answers to this question. Incidentally, why "*yet more* arrogance"?

Comment: The "yet more arrogance" comes from seeing it from the moderators of stackexchange software development. I wasn't expecting to see it on a puzzling site.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy if you have a problem with the software development stack exchange moderators, complain about it on *their* meta - not ours

Answer (score 11):

### The facts

Let's just get all the facts and context clear first, for anyone else who might be reading.

- Your answer was to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/54563/5373), and its complete text was:

  > When the first gamer comes to the pile for the last time there must be between 1 and 9 Euro in the pile. So the controller is worth between 1 and 9 Euro. The controller is not much use because there are no games to play with it. This questions also suggests that gamers are too stupid to use a calculator or sell games for different prices, so not a realistic question.
- Of the three users who deleted your answer (Beastly Gerbil, Rubio, and myself), only one was a ♦ moderator. BG and I are simply community members, who have the ability to help with site cleanup tasks due to our past contributions to the site.

### **Should your answer have been deleted?**

My reasoning for voting to delete it and flagging it as "not an answer" was that it **doesn't answer the question properly in the spirit it was asked**. The question is about an ideal mathematical situation; you can tell from the tags on it that it's meant to be solved by mathematical reasoning rather than real-world knowledge.

Your only attempt at an answer was "*the controller is worth between 1 and 9 Euro*", which is pretty much obvious from the question. Clearly you can say much more than this about the worth of the controller, so this is kind of useless - like seeing a question about how old somebody is and responding that their age must be a positive number.

The rest of your post was more like commentary and criticism of the question. You said "*The controller is not much use because there are no games to play with it*" and concluded that it's "*not a realistic question*". Well, it's not intended to be realistic - like I said, the context of gaming and controllers is only there as a wrapper to the underlying mathematical puzzle - and furthermore, commentary like this belongs in the **comments** section, not the answer box, unless it actually answers the question. Once you've participated here for a while and earned some reputation, you'll be able to leave comments on any post.

### Was it arrogant to delete it?

No; **that's how Stack Exchange sites work.** See [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) in the help centre, as well as the description of responsibilites for the [answer deletion privilege](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). We were helping to keep the site tidy, ensuring that it doesn't devolve into a discussion forum with a thread of non-answers posted below a question. If you stick around and earn some reputation, you too will be able to take part in tasks like this and help maintain the site. If you're unwilling to accept that non-answers need to be removed, then I'm afraid Stack Exchange may not be the right place for you.

Answer (score 2):

I was one of the people who voted to delete, and here is why:

[The question itself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/54563/18250) was

> How much was the controller worth?

The answer you gave was this:

> When the first gamer comes to the pile for the last time there must be between 1 and 9 Euro in the pile. So the controller is worth between 1 and 9 Euro. The controller is not much use because there are no games to play with it. This questions also suggests that gamers are too stupid to use a calculator or sell games for different prices, so not a realistic question.

To start - the answer 'between 1 and 9 Euros' is ridiculously too broad and doesn't provide an answer. It's like asking 'which fruit was picked out of the bowl' and someone giving the answer 'it must be one of the fruits that was in the bowl so either a banana, apple or an orange.' *Anyone* could have told you that.

Secondly the rest of your answer is unnecessary, irrelevant and should be posted as a comment. A second reason I decided to delete this as 'not an answer'.

Lastly I'll point out that Rubio was the only moderator to VTD. You say 'Is this yet more arrogance from a moderator on a site that is supposed to be fun?' - what do you mean 'yet more' - you provide no eveidence for anything else. Sure this site is meant to be a bit more fun than others - but answers are still taken seriously here.

Answers should answer the question - yours didn't really at all and therefore that is why I VTD.

Comment: The answer is not too broad. The puzzle was phrased in such a way that any number between 1 and 9 is a correct answer!

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy the question is looking for a specific answer - i.e. a single number. You had given an answer which just said it must be one of these numbers - you'd narrowed it down to 90%. That is too broad

Comment: The question does not provide enough information to result in a specific number. If the answer is too broad then the question is too broad so it too should have been deleted if you are to follow your own logic.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy the question is not too broad - see the accepted answer

Comment: I think we've got to the root of the problem in these comments. @PaulMcCarthy, the reason the answer can't be any number between 1 and 9 is because of the information given in the original question, specifically "They got as many Euros as there were games in the collection originally for each game.". This narrows down the amount of money to square numbers, refined to even square numbers with "...but the first gamer came to a take...". Let me know if there's still some confusion with the wording of the question.

Comment: Sorry! I think I missed the part about for each game when I first attempted the puzzle. It would read better if the sentence was restructured so that it started with for each game. It is still my fault for not reading it carefully enough and seeing this I agree that it was correct to delete my answer. Sorry for wasting everyone's time on this.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy don't worry glad everything's cleared up :)

Answer (score 0):

The full text of this answer was

> When the first gamer comes to the pile for the last time there must be between 1 and 9 Euro in the pile. So the controller is worth between 1 and 9 Euro. The controller is not much use because there are no games to play with it. This questions also suggests that gamers are too stupid to use a calculator or sell games for different prices, so not a realistic question.

This doesn't answer the question. The question - [Videogame salesmen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/54563/25966) - is asking to solve a puzzle about how much each game was worth *specifically*. You answer in between 1-9, which is... every single number that is under 10, because it has to be under ten. You don't answer the question on how much the controller was worth, you just say 'its one of the options given'. You can see how that doesn't really answer the question.

If I ask *What color is a pizza? Green, blue, purple, red, or black?* and you answer *it's either green, blue, purple, red, or black*... that **doesn't answer the question**.

You also say that the people in the puzzle are stupid, so that's not very constructive.

Comment: Technically he doesn't call anyone stupid - he's saying that the wording of the *puzzle* suggests they're stupid. Still, the rest of this is spot-on.

Comment: Every number from 1 to 9 is a valid answer. As I've been saying, it's not a good puzzle.